# can we get the ready made setting bundle?

Tags: iphone

can i get setting bundle ready made so it can easily deploy in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings bundle is always there to be added directly. You will need to write down the code, to make use of it. See [NSUserDefaults Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that purpose.

To add settings bundle - 
Go to Resources--> Add New File --> Resources --> Settings Bundle

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has a built in template which should be your starting point:
go to file -> new file -> resource -> settings bundle -> next
it will add the settings bundle to the app and it will have some default types built in.  You can customize it from there as much as you would like.
for more information on customization:
[PSPreferenceSpecifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RootContent.html) - from Apple